# Meteor - Publish just the count for a collection

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Is it possible to publish just the count for a collection to the user? I want to display the total count on the homepage, but not pass all the data to the user. This is what I tried but it does not work:

```
Meteor.publish('task-count', function () {
    return Tasks.find().count();
});

this.route('home', { 
    path: '/',
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('task-count');
    }
});
```

When I try this I get an endless loading animation.

Comment: is those `Tasks` belong to users or anything ? Why i am asking is that you can maintain that count inside `users` collection iteself and get it from there

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Meteor.publish` functions should return cursors, but here you're returning directly a `Number` which is the total count of documents in your `Tasks` collection.

Counting documents in Meteor is a surprisingly more difficult task than it appears if you want to do it the proper way : using a solution both elegant and effective.

The package [ros:publish-counts](https://atmospherejs.com/ros/publish-counts) (a fork of [tmeasday:publish-counts](https://atmospherejs.com/tmeasday/publish-counts)) provides accurate counts for small collections (100-1000) or "nearly accurate" counts for larger collections (tens of thousands) using the `fastCount` option.

You can use it this way :

```
// server-side publish (small collection)
Meteor.publish("tasks-count",function(){
  Counts.publish(this,"tasks-count",Tasks.find());
});

// server-side publish (large collection)
Meteor.publish("tasks-count",function(){
  Counts.publish(this,"tasks-count",Tasks.find(), {fastCount: true});
});

// client-side use
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  tasksCount:function(){
    return Counts.get("tasks-count");
  }
});
```

You'll get a client-side reactive count as well as a server-side reasonably performant implementation.

This problem is discussed in a (paid) bullet proof Meteor lesson which is a recommended reading : https://bulletproofmeteor.com/

Answer (score 8):

I would use a `Meteor.call`

Client:

```
 var count; /// Global Client Variable

 Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.call("count", function (error, result) {
      count = result;
    })
 });
```

return `count` in some helper

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
   count: function () {
     return Tasks.find().count();
   }
})
```

*Note this solution would not be reactive. However if reactivity is desired it can be incorporated.

Comment: is there a reactive approach?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I hope my answer might help others who need this info as I did.

I sometimes need some miscellaneous but reactive data to display indicators in the UI and documents count is a good example.

1. Create a reusable (exported) client-side only collection that won't be imported on the server (to avoid creating unnecessary database collection). Note the name passed as argument ("misc" here).

```js
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";

const Misc = new Mongo.Collection("misc");

export default Misc;
```

2. Create a publication on the server that accepts `docId` and the name of the `key` where the count will be saved (with a default value). The collection name to publish to
   is the one used to create the client only collection ("misc"). The `docId` value does not matter much, it just needs to be unique among all Misc docs to avoid conflicts. See [Meteor docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-publish) for details about the publication behavior.

```js
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import { check } from "meteor/check";
import { Shifts } from "../../collections";

const COLL_NAME = "misc";

/* Publish the number of shifts that need revision in a 'misc' collection
 * to a document specified as `docId` and optionally to a specified `key`. */
Meteor.publish("shiftsToReviseCount", function({ docId, key = "count" }) {
  check(docId, String);
  check(key, String);

  let initialized = false;
  let count = 0;

  const observer = Shifts.find(
    { needsRevision: true },
    { fields: { _id: 1 } }
  ).observeChanges({
    added: () => {
      count += 1;

      if (initialized) {
        this.changed(COLL_NAME, docId, { [key]: count });
      }
    },

    removed: () => {
      count -= 1;
      this.changed(COLL_NAME, docId, { [key]: count });
    },
  });

  if (!initialized) {
    this.added(COLL_NAME, docId, { [key]: count });
    initialized = true;
  }

  this.ready();

  this.onStop(() => {
    observer.stop();
  });
});
```

3. On the client, import the collection, decide of a `docId` string (can be saved in a constant), subscribe to the publication and fetch the appropriate document. Voilà!

```js
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import { withTracker } from "meteor/react-meteor-data";
import Misc from "/collections/client/Misc";

const REVISION_COUNT_ID = "REVISION_COUNT_ID";

export default withTracker(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe("shiftsToReviseCount", {
    docId: REVISION_COUNT_ID,
  }).ready();

  const { count } = Misc.findOne(REVISION_COUNT_ID) || {};

  return { count };
});
```