# How get a collection's count on the server to the client?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to get a collection's count from the server to the client. I want to use it for paging and just so users will know about the number of documents available. It's important the count does update if documents are added or removed.

One problem is paging, where I'm limiting the amount of documents sent to the client with publish/subscribe. But in the case below, the client will not know if the MyPix collection does contain more than 4 documents:

```
Meteor.publish('MyPix', function(cursor) {
    return MyPix.find({}, {limit:4, skip:cursor});
})
```

Comment: You should try using tmeasday;publish-counts : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948046/meteor-publish-just-the-count-for-a-collection/27948339#27948339

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is abit tricky,

a quick solution is to use this package, [publish-counts](https://github.com/percolatestudio/publish-counts)

**Server**

```
Meteor.publish('publication', function() {
   Counts.publish(this, 'numberOfPosts', Posts.find());
   Counts.publish(this, 'numberOfUsers', Users.find());
});
```

**Client**

```
Meteor.subscribe('publication')
```

then to get `numberofUsers` or `numberOfPosts`

```
Counts.get('numberOfUsers') // returns numberOfUSers users
```